# nginx Django Admin JS static files 404 error

Tags: django, nginx

I am almost done building my website but while creating an autogenerating slug in Django admin, I found it to be unresponsive. When i looked at the console of my browser i see a lot of JS error warnings. The nginx is correctly sending the css files, but there seems to be issues with respect to some admin js files. It is unable to read files in the admin/js/vendor/* . Any help or advise would be greatly appreciated.

```
#settings.py

import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/checklist/



# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True


ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'Blog',
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Blog.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'debug': DEBUG,
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',


            ],
        },
    },
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'django_project.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'django_project.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'django',
        'USER': 'django',
        'PASSWORD': 'eJf9IHxaMe',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/


STATIC_URL = '/static/'
#STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static")

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    #'/var/www/static/',
]

STATIC_ROOT =  '/home/django/django_project/django_project/static'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/django/django_project/django_project/media'
```

## nginx

```
upstream app_server {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    client_max_body_size 4G;
    server_name _;

    keepalive_timeout 5;

    # Your Django project's media files - amend as required
    location /media  {
        alias /home/django/django_project/django_project/media;
    }

    # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    location /static {
        alias /home/django/django_project/django_project/static; 
    }

    # Proxy the static assests for the Django Admin panel
    location /static/admin {
       alias /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }
}
```

## Console Error

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://myipaddress/static/admin/js/vendor/xregexp/xregexp.min.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://myipaddress/static/admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
jquery.init.js:7 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined(anonymous function) @ jquery.init.js:7
actions.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined(anonymous function) @ actions.js:2(anonymous function) @ actions.js:139
prepopulate.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined(anonymous function) @ prepopulate.js:2(anonymous function) @ prepopulate.js:34
http://myipaddress/static/admin/js/vendor/xregexp/xregexp.min.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
myipaddress Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function(anonymous function) @ myipaddress/:220(anonymous function) @ myipaddress/:234
myipaddress/:259 Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
```

Comment: Try `./manage.py collectstatic`. This will collect all static files in your designated django static file dir, including the admin's static files.

Comment: Yes , we have tried collectstatic but  again the problem seems to be only with the admin/js/vendor folder js files. It reads the other js files but throws a 404 error for the jquery and other files in the vendor folder.

Comment: You also may need to set `STATIC_DIRS`in your `settings.py` and list your `vendor` folder.`STATIC_DIRS` is the list of directories that you want to collect in your `STATIC_ROOT`

Comment: Thanks Aaron, the problem was because the vendor folder was missing in python 2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin//. I shouldn't have overlooked the nginx error log. It's working fine now.